# How to assign c++ lambda into function pointer?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, lambda, assign

I wish to know how to assign a lambda to a function pointer, is this a viable syntax? I tried this:

```
    const size_t N = 3;
    typedef void (*pf)();
    pf F1 = [=](){ cout << N << endl; }
```

It fails to compile, saying:

```
no viable conversion from '(lambda at xxx.cpp:6:3)' to 'pf' (aka 'void (*)()')
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You can only do this with a non-capturing lambda. For a lambda that captures anything, a function pointer would have no way to encode the captured values.

Comment: There is no way to assign that lambda to a function pointer.  It contains more information than what would fit in a pointer.

Comment: This episode of C++ Weekly may help some https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aC-aAiS5Wuc